# How do I concatenate a string in a PHP Array Element?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, string-concatenation

I am customizing  wordpress blog and I have a need to make custom sidebar widgets.  My PHP is rusty at best. What I am trying to do is concatenate a php variable into a string being set as an array element.  here is the code I am using, it doesn't seem to work.  All it does is print the stylesheet directory at the top of every page:

```
if ( function_exists("register_sidebar") )
    register_sidebar(array(
        "before_widget" => "<div class=\"rounded_box\"><div class=\"top_curve\"><img src=\"".bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/images/top_curve.jpg\" alt=\"Top\" width=\"247\" height=\"9\" /></div><div class=\"middle\">",
        "after_widget" => "</div><div class=\"bottom_curve\"><img src=\"".bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/images/bottom_curve.jpg\" alt=\"Bottom\"  /></div></div>",
        "before_title" => "<h2>",
        "after_title" => "</h2>",
    ));
```

so as you can see here I am trying to concatenate the `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` into 2 of the elements.  This doesn't work properly.  It just ends up printing it at the top of the page before the `doctype`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress, but at a guess, the bloginfo() class is echoing things out rather than returning a string.

Comment: if this is the case, then how would i get around it?

Comment: Aaaaah. R. You are correct. Russ, use get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo)('stylesheet_directory') will echo the stylesheet directory. When you declare the array, you are effectively writing to stdout. This is why it will show on top of the page. What you are looking for is [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

Comment: As an aside, a good example of why 'view' type helpers shouldn't echo on their own, but return the output for the calling script to control.

Answer (score 0):

Use [implode](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
string implode  ( string $glue  , array $pieces  )
string implode ( array $pieces )
```

Join array elements with a glue string.

Comment: i am not trying to join the array elements.  I am trying to concatenante the `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` into 2 of the elements but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a comma at the end. It might be that. Remove it and test.
I've also replace \" with a singe '.

**UPDATE**
replaced bloginfo() with get_bloginfo().

```
if ( function_exists("register_sidebar") )
{
  $args =array(
  "before_widget" => "<div class='rounded_box'><div class='top_curve'><img src='".get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/images/top_curve.jpg' alt='Top' width='247' height='9' /></div><div class='middle'>",
  "after_widget" => "</div><div class='bottom_curve'><img src='".get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/images/bottom_curve.jpg' alt='Bottom' /></div></div>",
  "before_title" => "<h2>",
  "after_title" => "</h2>");'

  register_sidebar($args);
}
```

Comment: this has the same effect of printing the stylesheet directory at the top of the page

Comment: What if you try `$before_wid = "string 1".bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."string 2";` And then you put `"before_widget" => $before_wid` ?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not *technically* the answer to your question, but have you considered:

```
if ( function_exists("register_sidebar") )
    $ssheet_dir = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
    register_sidebar(array(
            "before_widget" => "<div class=\"rounded_box\"><div class=\"top_curve\"><img src=\"$ssheet_dir/images/top_curve.jpg\" alt=\"Top\" width=\"247\" height=\"9\" /></div><div class=\"middle\">",
            "after_widget" => "</div><div class=\"bottom_curve\"><img src=\"$ssheet_dir/images/bottom_curve.jpg\" alt=\"Bottom\"  /></div></div>",
            "before_title" => "<h2>",
            "after_title" => "</h2>",
    ));
```

It would be easier and faster -- it would only involve making the bloginfo function call once.